# Spring Boot test doesn't find bean from sibling package

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-ioc

I have a `@SpringBootTest` annotated test class which wants to make use of a test utility:

```
package org.myproject.server;

// ...

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class ServerITest {

    private @Autowired TestHelperBean helper;

    // ...
}
```

This works fine if the `TestHelperBean` is defined in the same package as the test class (or in a sub-package).

```
package org.myproject.server;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class TestHelperBean {
    // ...
}
```

If I move it to a sibling package though, the component is not found:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.myproject.**testutils**.TestHelperBean' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

I guess that component scanning by default only looks in the test class' package and sub-packages – but is there a way to override this default? I tried to add the `@ComponentScan` annotation to my test, but this didn't seem to have any effect:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ComponentScan("org.myproject")
public class ServerITest {
    // ...
}
```

Is there a way to use beans from sibling packages in Spring Boot tests?

Comment: Check to make sure that TestHelperBean is annotated properly.  It should not be a problem if that class is part of the same project.

Comment: The TestHelperBean is annotated with `@Component` - see updated question. This is correct AFAIK.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `@ComponentScan` annotation **doesn't work** if placed **on the test class**.

This can be done instead:

- Add a nested class to your test, and annotate that class with `@Configuration` and the `@ComponentScan` annotation.
- Use an `@Import` annotation on the test class. Note that `@Import` only allows to  add individual classes to the context.
- If don't mind adding the classes from the sibling package in other situations as well, you can also place the `@ComponentScan` annotation on any `@Configuration` class (or `@Component`, `@Service`, etc.) that is already included in the context.

Answer (score 1):

With componentscan annotation you can specify '*' to cover all subpackages under base package as well.

```
@ComponentScan({"org.myproject.*", "org.newproj.*"})
```

It covers all subpackages under "org.myproject" and "org.newproj".

Example package structure

```
org.myproject 
org.myproject.abc 
org.myproject.abcd 
org.myproject.xyz.abc

org.newproj 
org.newproj.abc 
org.newproj.xyz
```

OR

Register bean with Configuration/SpringBootApplication class

```
@Bean
private TestHelperBean helper() {
    return new TestHelperBean();
}
```

Comment: I tried this out, but it doesn't have any effect :(

Comment: I've also tried your second proposal, i.e. I've added the `@Bean` annotated method to the test class, but it doesn't work either :(

Answer (score 0):

In the component scan you can add multiple packages the need to be scanned

```
@ComponentScan({"org.myproject","org.myproject. server","org.myproject. sibilings"})
```

Comment: I tried this out with the appropriate package names, but it doesn't have any effect :-(

Comment: it included the package of the TestHelperBean

Answer (score -1):

The other answers regarding the use of `ComponentScan` are correct. However, [the Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html#using-boot-locating-the-main-class) strongly advises that "your main application class be in a root package above other classes". From personal experience I can say that deviating from this practice will result in more trouble than it's worth.